# Sol2 And Lua Sandbox

Tags: c++, lua, sandbox

I'm trying to load and execute a script on it's own environment using the `lua_setupvalue`. This script will use the usertypes I've already registered prior to loading the script. The problem is the script is unable to find the earlier registered function and classes.

```
std::string lua_code("print(entity.getId())");
sol::state state;

lua_newtable(state);
//register classes and functions here
state.new_usertype<Entity>("Entity", 
  sol::constructors<sol::types<>>(),
  "getId", &Entity::getId
);
state.set_function("print", print);

lua_loadstring(state, lua_code.c_str()); //load unsafe lua code
lua_pushvalue(state, 1); //create a copy of the table
lua_setupvalue(state, -2, 1); //set the environment for the script earlier
state["entity"] = entity; //pass the entity object
lua_call(state, 0, 0);
```

After running this I'm getting the error:

```
attempt to call a nil value(global 'getComponent')
```

What I'm attempting here is to reuse one lua_state for all entities(in an Entity Component System) scripts. That's why I'm trying to only register the classes and functions once and call the entity scripts on different environments but with the earlier registered data available to them.